# Update columns In a Teradata Table using data from another table

Tags: sql, teradata

I have seen many posts and followed the syntax to write the below query. But it is still given the error "`Column/Parameter wm_ad_hoc.temp.temp does not exist`"

Please assist in figuring out what am I doing wrong here.

```sql
UPDATE temp 
FROM   wm_ad_hoc.OWNED_ITEM_STORE_DLY temp, 
       wm_ad_hoc.OWNED_ITEM_STORE_DLY_UTIL util 
SET    temp.VENDOR_STOCK_ID = util. VENDOR_STOCK_ID, 
       temp.ON_HAND_EACH_QTY = util. ON_HAND_EACH_QTY, 
       temp.VENDOR_STOCK_ID = util.VENDOR_STOCK_ID 
WHERE  temp. VENDOR_NBR = util. VENDOR_NBR 
AND    temp.WMI_ITEM_NBR = util.WMI_ITEM_NBR 
AND    temp. store_nbr = util. store_nbr 
AND    temp.BUSINESS_DATE = util.BUSINESS_DATE
```

Comment: Are u sure the about error? Double temps here 'm_ad_hoc.temp.temp' look confusing

Comment: For one you have spaces between your table and column names. `WHERE  temp. VENDOR_NBR = util. VENDOR_NBR ` should be `WHERE  temp.VENDOR_NBR = util.VENDOR_NBR `

Comment: @JNevill spaces doesn`t change anything, sql just ignores them

Comment: But they are really ugly and it's an affront to common decency. Honestly, I didn't know that it didn't care. I just tried it and my database was OK with it. I feel like I need to purge DBQL and my client's history though. ick.

Answer (score 4):

You need to not qualify your `SET` columns.  So:

```
UPDATE temp 
FROM   wm_ad_hoc.OWNED_ITEM_STORE_DLY temp, 
       wm_ad_hoc.OWNED_ITEM_STORE_DLY_UTIL util 
SET    VENDOR_STOCK_ID = util.VENDOR_STOCK_ID, 
       ON_HAND_EACH_QTY = util.ON_HAND_EACH_QTY, 
       VENDOR_STOCK_ID = util.VENDOR_STOCK_ID
...
```

Comment: Had to remove the qualify from the SET part but had to keep them for the WHERE clauses.